# Mcrypt PHP extension required in laravel 4.2 in shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel-4, web-deployment

Hi I am deploying a Laravel 4.2 project in shared hosting. When I hit the URL of my project it shows the following

```
Mcrypt PHP extension required
```

PHP version of my shared hosting site is 5.6 and my pc PHP version where I have developed my application is 5.5.

I have dig into the Internet and find the problem that is because of PHP version.

How can I change my application PHP version to shared hosting PHP version?

Comment: nothing to do with versioning. you just need to enable mcrypt on your server.

Comment: problem is I am using shared hosting

Comment: @BugzillaTest contact them and ask to install that extension, or change provider (could be a good argument to have them comply to your request)